# If cases broken when using rollup

Tags: mysql, rollup

I'm trying to make a column have a specific value on the rollup-row, but when I add an "if", all other rows get the last value in that column.

Why? And what is the correct way to solve it?

Fiddle:
http://rextester.com/TTYI19512

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE ru (ru_id INT KEY, name VARCHAR(20));
INSERT INTO ru VALUES (1, 'A'),(2, 'B');

CREATE TABLE rud (rud_id INT KEY, ru_id INT, value INT);
INSERT INTO rud VALUES (1, 1, 3), (2, 1, 5), (3, 2, 4), (4, 2, 9);

SELECT
   ru_id,
   IF(ru_id IS NULL, 'Total', name) as name,
   COUNT(rud.value),
   SUM(rud.value)
FROM ru
   INNER JOIN rud USING (ru_id)
GROUP BY ru_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Current Result:

```
+-------+-------+------------------+----------------+
| ru_id | name  | COUNT(rud.value) | SUM(rud.value) |
+-------+-------+------------------+----------------+
|     1 | B     |                2 |              8 |
|     2 | B     |                2 |             13 |
|  NULL | Total |                4 |             21 |
+-------+-------+------------------+----------------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+-------+-------+------------------+----------------+
| ru_id | name  | COUNT(rud.value) | SUM(rud.value) |
+-------+-------+------------------+----------------+
|     1 | A     |                2 |              8 |
|     2 | B     |                2 |             13 |
|  NULL | Total |                4 |             21 |
+-------+-------+------------------+----------------+
```

Comment: _“Why?”_ - because you are trying to select a column that is not part of the grouping – `name`. That is illegal in “pure” SQL, and MySQL only allows it if the server is configured to ignore this error (in which case you get a “random” value from one of the records in the group.)

Comment: @CBroe: a random value in the group would be nice, but now I get a value outside the group.

Comment: @CBroe: That's wrong. According to the SQL standard you can select all aggregations (i.e. `SUM` etc.), and columns in group by, and columns functionally depending on them. (Well with the table given, `name` isn't dependent on `ru_id` - or at least this is not known to the DBMS, but even when you change `KEY` to `PRIMARY KEY` we still get the same wrong result.)

Comment: Seems to be a flaw in the DBMS. The query looks okay to me. Be aware that `KEY` only means `INDEX` in MySQL. Make this `PRIMARY KEY` to get a unique identifyer.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: You are correct that all columns can be used inside aggregate functions, even if they are not part of the grouping - but IF is not an aggregate function.

Comment: @thorsten-kettner: using KEY in CREATE TABLE, at least gives me a primary key in mariadb. MAX around just the name, to use what CBroe called "pure sql", works.

Comment: @CBroe: But `name` is identified by `ru_id`. For one `ru_id` we are supposed to get exactly one `name`. In other words: `name` is functionally dependent on `ru_id` and thus allowed. (Don't let it confuse you that many DBMS are not standard-compliant in this point and force you to list `name` in group by too or use an aggregate function on `name`. This is a weakness in those DBMS and often a nuisance.)

Comment: "KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX. The key attribute PRIMARY KEY can also be specified as just KEY when given in a column definition." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table.html

Comment: @Puggan Se: Ah, sorry, I didn't know that. MySQL seems to be pretty broken concerning ROLLUP. In rextester it doesn't show 'Total'. It isn't aware that `ru_id` is null in that row.

Answer (score 2):

Only aggregation-functions and columns included in the group-by are allowed in pure sql, so by putting a aggregation-function around the name-column, it make it an allowed query, and gives the expected result.

```
SELECT
   ru_id,
   IF(ru_id IS NULL, 'Total', MAX(name)) as name,
   COUNT(rud.value),
   SUM(rud.value)
FROM ru
   INNER JOIN rud USING (ru_id)
GROUP BY ru_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Thanks to @ThorstenKettner & @CBroe for the contributions in the comment field.

Comment: above works in mariadb, to get the mysql-fiddle to work: IF(COUNT(DISTINCT ru_id) > 1, 'Total', MAX(name)) as name,

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your if condition with an aggregate function,like MAX (it doesnt matter since it`s  a string,could be also MIN)

```
SELECT IFNULL(ru_id,'Total'), MAX(IF(ru_id IS NULL, 'Total', name)) as name,
 COUNT(rud.value), SUM(rud.value) 
FROM ru INNER JOIN rud USING (ru_id) 
GROUP BY ru_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

You can make the total appear for the id but not for the name,in the last row name will be random.Also your current result dont display total either.

Comment: With max I get: A, B, B, not the expected "A, B, Total"

Comment: found a workaround: IF(COUNT(DISTINCT ru_id) > 1, 'Total', name)

Comment: using the max around the name, inside the if, also works for me.
IF(ru_id IS NULL, 'Total', MAX(name))